# Issue Using the Chat

Tags: bug, chat

I have 23 rep on superuser but when I click on a chatroom it is still saying I do not have enough rep.

Is it a bug or something? I have emailed superuser support but there has been no response, I emailed stack exchange support - again no response.

Comment: Well... I'm blaming you... I went to Superuser and it logged me out of all sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be patient, it sometimes takes a little while for your chat reputation to be synchronized with your main account. If you've already waited a while, read on.

Since you haven't yet hit 200 rep on any site, you'll also need to be careful about which Stack Exchange site is considered the "parent" of your chat user. You've been a member of Stack Overflow longer than you've been registered at Super User, so your parent site is probably still Stack Overflow. Go to `chat.superuser.com`, click your username next to the search bar, find where it says "parent user", click "change", and set it to Super User.

[image: where to change]